# How to import an image sequence into Blenders video editor with each image playing for one second?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to tell Blender somewhere, that each image should be playing for a certain amount of time or frames when importing them onto the timeline of the video sequence editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can!

Import the frames as a sequence of images like you normally would (which will make each image play for one frame). With the image sequence strip selected, click Strip > Separate Images (or tap the Y key), then you can set the frame length of each image in the sequence.